# what to write in manifest-file when calling an activity in another app with result?

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, manifest, registerforactivityresult

wenn I call an activity which sends a result in the same app, I write in the manifest-file:

```
    <activity android:name=".UnterActivity />
```

and the intent I define with:

```
    val unter = Intent(this, UnterActivity::class.java) 
    secondActivityWithResult.launch(unter)
```

What do I have to change when the activity thats send the result is not in the same app but in an different one ?

The second app I call with:

```
    val pack = "a1.a1.gerufen3"
    val unter = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pack)!!
    secondActivityWithResult.launch(unter)
```

What must I write in the manifest-file so that the first app can get the result from the second app ?
I handle the result with:

```
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
```

When I call the activity inside the calling app I have success, but what to do when the activity is outside the calling app ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You don’t have to declare anything in your manifest for activities in other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution in another forum. It is:

```
    val unter = Intent()
    unter.setClassName("a1.a1.gerufen3", "a1.a1.gerufen3.MainActivity")
    unter.putExtra("keyger1", B.edit1.text.toString())
    resultabfrage.launch(unter)
```